# How to update key of dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
if (userFollowingArray[indexPath.row]["watcher_following"] as! Bool) == false {
    let dict : NSMutableDictionary = userFollowingArray[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
    print(dict)
    dict["watcher_following"] = 1
    self.userFollowingArray[indexPath.row] = dict as! Dictionary<String, Any>
}
```

I want to update `watcher_following` key with `true/false` but it throws an exception.

> [_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSP__
>   _swift_setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: change `let dict` to `var dict` and then try

Comment: is it in tapped action?

Comment: Why NSMutableDictionary instead of a Swift dictionary in a var? Why force casting everything? This is Swift but this looks more like Objective-C than Swift 3...

Comment: Now its working
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift

- Declare `userFollowingArray` as Swift Array

  ```
  var userFollowingArray = [[String:Any]]()
  ```
- Get the `Dictionary` as `var`iable

  ```
  var dict = userFollowingArray[indexPath.row]
  ```
- Check the value

  ```
  if dict["watcher_following"] as! Bool == false {
  ```
- Update it if necessary and assign the dictionary back to the array.

  ```
      dict["watcher_following"] = true
      userFollowingArray[indexPath.row] = dict
  }
  ```

  The last step is necessary due to value semantics

It's much more convenient to use a custom struct or class rather than a dicionary.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var` for mutable types, `let` is only for immutable/constant types.  not needed to use objective c `NSMutableDictionary` type.

```
if dict["watcher_following"] as! Bool == false {
    var dict : Dictionary<String, Any> = userFollowingArray[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    dict["watcher_following"] = 1
    self.userFollowingArray[indexPath.row] = dict as! Dictionary<String, Any>
}
```